# dequeueReusableCell returns empty cell after table initialization

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that is initialized with three rows when loaded. Later, I want to extract cell data (from labels) and use it when that specific cell is selected by the user.

Even though initialization works well and I can see all the data being displayed, the dequeueReusableCell in the didSelectRowAt methods returns empty cells, with no data.

What is the problem?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Whoopse, dequeueing the cell failed")
    }
    let title = cell.articleLabel.text
    // Do other stuff

}
```

The title variable above will be empty, even though it's data is shown on the display.

Comment: Do not extract any data from the cell, use the data from the datasource that the cell is _presenting_.

Comment: And never call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: @Alladinian The table is showing a list of folders and files. When the user selects a cell, I have to get an ID for that file from the cell. I wouldn't know which file is selected just by the rowIndex.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks. What exactly goes wrong when `dequeueReusableCell` is used outside of `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: `dequeueReusableCell` will return another cell not the clicked 1 ,  your need is `cellForRow`

Comment: How does the cell know about this ID?

Comment: @Vicarious In `cellForRowAt` you set the cell's `articleLabel` based on some data model, right? Use that same data model to get that same value in `didSelectRowAt`. Cells are not your data source, your data model is your data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleTableViewCell else {
    fatalError("Whoopse, dequeueing the cell failed")
}
```

with ( **not recommended** )

```
guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath) as? ArticleTableViewCell else {
    fatalError("Whoopse, dequeueing the cell failed")
}
```

but ##better##  is to access the data source array with the clicked index

```
let item = arr[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Do not use the `cellForRow` option. Just use the direct data model access option.

Comment: you obviously see better didn't you ? i didn't edit it , it was here before your comment